# JavaFX: Load String from File and set to Label

Tags: java, javafx

Not only have I lost 5 hours but also almost my mind because of this problem.

I load a String from a Txt File and want to set it to the label sourceURL. Before I check it in System.out.println("Firstline is : " + brTest.readLine()); and it shows the String correctli. But then the UI pops up and the label is empty.

It looks like it couldnt load it and needs to refresh. Do you know anything here?

**DashBoardController**

```
    import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.text.Font;
import javafx.stage.DirectoryChooser;

public class DashboardController {

    @FXML
    private Label userFeedback;

    @FXML
    private Font x1;

    @FXML
    private Label sourceURL;

    @FXML
    private Label targetURL;

    @FXML
    public void initialize(){
        BufferedReader brTest;
        try {
            brTest = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File("settings/sourceurl.txt")));
            System.out.println("Firstline is : " + brTest.readLine());

            String temp = brTest.readLine();
            sourceURL.setText(brTest.readLine());
            sourceURL.setText(temp);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @FXML
    void convert(ActionEvent event) {

    }

    @FXML
    void openFolder(ActionEvent event) {

    }

    @FXML
    void selectSource(ActionEvent event) throws FileNotFoundException {
        //DirectoryChooser initialisieren
        DirectoryChooser directoryChooser = new DirectoryChooser();
        directoryChooser.setTitle("Quellordner wählen");

        //URL speichern
        File selectedDirectory = directoryChooser.showDialog(null);
        sourceURL.setText(selectedDirectory.getAbsolutePath());

        //Ordner erstellen
        File settings = new File("settings");
        settings.mkdir();

        //Datei erstellen und URL abspeichern
        PrintWriter printWriter = new PrintWriter("settings/sourceurl.txt");
        printWriter.println(selectedDirectory.getAbsolutePath());
        printWriter.close();
    }

    @FXML
    void selectTarget(ActionEvent event) {
        sourceURL.setText("sdfkjasdöfl");
    }

    @FXML
    void showInfo(ActionEvent event) {

    }

    @FXML
    void showSupport(ActionEvent event) {

    }
}
```

Dashboard

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.Pane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Dashboard extends Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        launch(args);
    }

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        //Pane laden
        Pane pane = (Pane) FXMLLoader.load(Dashboard.class.getResource("Dashboard.fxml"));

        //Stage einrichten
        stage.setScene(new Scene(pane));
        stage.setTitle("");
        stage.setResizable(false);
        stage.show();
    }

}
```

Comment: How many lines are in your file? And also, did you test it without println and temp variable - with only one `brTest.readLine()` statement?

Comment: If you are using an IDE like Eclipse, IntelliJ then use debug mode to check values in variables.

Comment: If you call `readLine()` on a `BufferedReader` twice, it will not return the same line of text. Store the result of `readLine()` in a variable and then set the `Label`'s text.

Comment: thank everbody! my fault was to call twice brTest.readline() and i still just had one line text in my file. what an amateur! 

THHX!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to set the text of a `TextField` during loading, you have to get the ID by using the `lookup()` function(in JavaFX):

```
initialize(){
     scene = Pane.getScene();   
     TextField sourceURL= (TextField) scene .lookup("#sourceURL");
     sourceURL.setText("your text");
}
```

Comment: no - while you can do something like your suggestion (why would you though?) that has nothing to do with OP's problem (which was a simple mistake, as noted in her comment)